# Give objects each a set random atribute for objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 30 objects in an array. One of the attributes in each object is `question_order`. I want to make a javascript function that gives an order to the objects. To do this I would need to give each object's attribute `question_order` a number of 1-30 and each `question_order` number would have to be unique. What would be the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: an array is a data structure for sorted items. why do you need another indicator for sorting?

Comment: because I need to randomize them each time while having a set order for the variables

Comment: sounds reasonable, just take the array of objects and add an order propery in advance and shuffle later.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of indexes and shuffle if. Then you can loop through your items and assign a `question_order` based on the shuffled array:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var index = array.length;
    while (--index >0 ) {
        let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * index);
        [array[index],  array[randIndex]] = [ array[randIndex], array[index]];
    }
    return array;
  }
let items =[
    {name: 0},
    {name: 1},
    {name: 2},
    {name: 3},
    {name: 4}
]

// make an index arr i.e [0,1,2,3] the same length as items
let indexes = shuffle(Array.from({length: items.length}, (_,i) => i))

// add question order
items.forEach((item, index) => item.question_order = indexes[index])

console.log(items)
```

But if you can already shuffle and array, why not just shuffle the original array and save yourself the extra work:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var index = array.length;
    while (--index >0 ) {
        let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * index);
        [array[index],  array[randIndex]] = [ array[randIndex], array[index]];
    }
    return array;
  }
let items =[
    {name: 0},
    {name: 1},
    {name: 2},
    {name: 3},
    {name: 4}
]

console.log(shuffle(items))
```